# How to access values of a class from a different method(out the class)

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have this peace of code and I am attempting to print out a dictionary in a class, how can I access the value from a different method and specifying the value to be printed

```
class Student:

    student_instance_dict            = {}

    def __init__(self, student):


        self.name = None 
        self.phoneNumber = 0


students = ['Mike', 'Dany']
for student in students:
    instance = Student(student)
    Student.student_instance_dict[student] = instance


    print (Student.student_instance_dict[student].name)#this prints out without any problems

def printUpdates(x):
    print (Student.student_instance_dict[student].x)

name = 'name'
printUpdates(name)
```

The las line returns AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'x'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Student.student_instance_dict[student].x` will check the object `Student.student_instance_dict[student]` for an attribute called `x`, which your objects don't have. It looks like what you're trying to do is create a function that will get the value of an attribute whose name is passed in as a string. For that, use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def printUpdates(x):
    print(getattr(Student.student_instance_dict[student], x))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution example and explanation